# Executing a Powershell function (which takes parameters) from Powershell command shell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which is a function and takes parameters. From with the powershell command shell, how do I execute a function? It seems like it works differently for different users.

Answer (score 7):

Is your script, simply a script or does it contain a function?  If it is a script and takes parameters it will look something like this:

```
-- top of file foo.ps1  --
param($param1, $param2)

<script here>
```

You invoke that just like a cmdlet excecpt that if you are running from the current dir you have to specify the path to the script like so:

```
.\foo.ps1 a b
```

Also note that you pass arguments to scripts (and functions) space separated just like you do with cmdlets.

You mentioned function, so if you script looks like this you have a couple of options:

```
-- top of file foo.ps1  --
function foo ($param1, $param2) {
    <script here>
}
```

If you run foo.ps1 like above, nothing will happen other than you will define a function called foo in a temporary scope and that scope will go away when the script exits. You could add a line to the bottom of the script that actually calls the foo function.   But perhaps you are intending on using this script more as a reusable function library.  In that case you probably want to `load` the functions into the current scope.  You can do that with the dot source operator `.` like so:

```
C:\PS> . .\foo.ps1
C:\PS> foo a b
```

Now function foo will be defined at the global level.  Note that you could do the same thing within another script which will load that function into the script's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post, maybe it is the right for you.
[How to pass command-line arguments to a PowerShell ps1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293907/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-powershell-ps1-file)

Anyway, the built-in $args variable is an array that holds all the command line arguments.