# Use powershell command in add_click

Tags: powershell

I do a basic powershell script with a window and a simple button,

On the add_click action i want to execute the "powershell -file $path" command to open another script

in the main the command works, but not when it is in the .add_click({ })

```
    #main
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$btn1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btn1.Text = "Button1"
$form.Controls.Add($btn1)

$path = "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\export_vers_test\test_cmd.ps1"
#powershell -file $path #Here it works

$btn1.add_Click({
    write-host $path
    powershell -file $path #Here it works doesn't works
})

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Can i have some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the string path to your powershell function.

Use paramters for that.

Your function:

```
function Set-ActionOnClic{ 
param($path)
    write-host $path
}
```

the call in the click event

```
$btn1.add_Click({
    Set-ActionOnClic -path $path
    #Run the script
    . $Path
})
```

Comment: It is not the problem,
without passing the parameter i can write-host the path, 
but what i want is to execute "powershell" command

Comment: try `. $Path` for the execution of the script.

Comment: ah but now i can't pass parameters  `. $path [-parameters]`

Comment: It's still possible to use parameters. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716234/executing-a-powershell-function-which-takes-parameters-from-powershell-command)

Comment: Just use $script:Path in the initil script and it should work.