# PowerShell run a 'function' (not a script) from a Windows Form add_click

Tags: function, powershell, tooltip, messagebox

I want to run a defined PowerShell function on an add_click event in a Windows form in that script.

I've found lots of examples of how to call a .ps1 script from a click, but not how to call a function.

[Use powershell command in add_click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760616/use-powershell-command-in-add-click)

So, here is my script in full. I am curious on two ways of outputting this information.

• Just open a PowerShell console and show the results in there (the `pause` will prevent it from closing), or
• In some kind of MessageBox (some more Windows Forms magic or techniques or tooltips, or whatever anyone thinks works well - such techniques are all very interesting to me).

```
function sysx {
    $System = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
    $Mem = [math]::Ceiling($System.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
    $wmi = gwmi -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer "."
    $LBTime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime)
    [TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $LBTime $(get-date)
    $s = "" ; if ($uptime.Days -ne 1) {$s = "s"}
    $uptime_string = "$($uptime.days) day$s $($uptime.hours) hr $($uptime.minutes) min $($uptime.seconds) sec"
    "$Mem GB"
    "Up: $uptime_string"
    pause
}

# Load Assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework   # For MessageBox

$MyIcon = [Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Command powershell).Path)

# Create Primary form
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Visible = $false
$objForm.WindowState = "minimized"
$objForm.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$objForm.add_Closing({ $objForm.ShowInTaskBar = $False })

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = $MyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Text = "TrayUtility"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $true

$objContextMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu

$ToggleMenuItemPS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemPS.Index = 1
$ToggleMenuItemPS.Text = "New PowerShell"
if (Test-Administrator) { $ToggleMenuItemPS.Text = "New PowerShell (Admin)" }
$ToggleMenuItemPS.add_Click({
    Start-Process PowerShell.exe
})

$ToggleMenuItemFunction = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Index = 2
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Text = "Mem and Uptime"
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.add_Click({
    # some way to call the 'sysx' function in a PowerShell console, MessageBox, tooltip, etc...
})

# Create an Exit Menu Item
$ExitMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ExitMenuItem.Index = 5
$ExitMenuItem.Text = "E&xit"
$ExitMenuItem.add_Click({
    $objForm.Close()
    $objNotifyIcon.visible = $false
})

# Add the Menu Items to the Context Menu
$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ToggleMenuItemPS)       | Out-Null
$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ToggleMenuItemFunction) | Out-Null
$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ExitMenuItem)           | Out-Null

# Assign the Context Menu
$objNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu
$objForm.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu

# Show the Form - Keep it open
$objForm.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$objForm.Dispose()
```

Comment: As for your specific post title --- [PowerShell run a 'function' (not a script) from a Windows Form add_click] ---, this is a very common thing to do. The code should work well before attaching it to a UI. There are tons of articles, videos, and sample code all over the web on this use case. You also have this [if (Test-Administrator) { $ToggleMenuItemPS.Text = "New PowerShell (Admin)" }] --- which that function is nowhere in your code. So, as posted this makes it fail to run at all. Variable and code have a scope, even for output. See my suggestion for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use only `sysx` there:

```
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.add_Click({sysx})
```

To show results in a message box tweak `sysx` a bit:

```
$wshshell = new-object -comobject Wscript.shell
$wsh.PopUp("$($Mem) GB`nUp: $($uptime_string)")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hopeful that would work, but using `sysx` on its own does nothing. No PowerShell window is opened, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you changed the sysx function like the second example to show message box?

Answer (score 0):

All code has scope, even for output. Your function will run, but since you are note telling the output where to go. I added the Test admin function since it was left out of your post.

I tested and validated the below and it works on my system, in a running PowerShell console/ISE/VSCode session. Meaning, it prints this output to the console (of course you can change that to send to a Message Box, et al) and start a new console as admin.

```
#region Begin code-behind logic
#
function Test-Administrator 
{
    ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::
    GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator") 
}

function Get-Sysx {
    $System  = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
    $Mem     = [math]::Ceiling($System.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
    $wmi     = gwmi -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer "."
    $LBTime  = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime)

    [TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $LBTime $(get-date)

    $s = "" 
    
    if ($uptime.Days -ne 1) {$s = "s"}

    $uptime_string = "$($uptime.days) day$s $($uptime.hours) hr $($uptime.minutes) min $($uptime.seconds) sec"
    "$Mem GB"
    "Up: $uptime_string"
    pause
}
#
#endregion End code behind logic

#region Begin GUI logic
#
# Load Assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework   # For MessageBox

$MyIcon = [Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Command powershell).Path)

# Create Primary form
$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Visible       = $false
$objForm.WindowState   = "minimized"
$objForm.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$objForm.add_Closing({ $objForm.ShowInTaskBar = $False })

$objNotifyIcon         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon    = $MyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Text    = "TrayUtility"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $true

$objContextMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu

$ToggleMenuItemPS       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemPS.Index = 1
$ToggleMenuItemPS.Text  = "New PowerShell"

if (Test-Administrator) { $ToggleMenuItemPS.Text = "New PowerShell (Admin)" }

$ToggleMenuItemPS.add_Click({
    Start-Process PowerShell.exe
})

$ToggleMenuItemFunction       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Index = 2
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Text  = "Mem and Uptime"
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.add_Click({
    Get-Sysx | Out-Host
})

# Create an Exit Menu Item
$ExitMenuItem       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ExitMenuItem.Index = 5
$ExitMenuItem.Text  = "E&xit"
$ExitMenuItem.add_Click({
    $objForm.Close()
    $objNotifyIcon.visible = $false
})

# Add the Menu Items to the Context Menu
[void]$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ToggleMenuItemPS)
[void]$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ToggleMenuItemFunction)
[void]$objContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($ExitMenuItem)

# Assign the Context Menu
$objNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu
$objForm.ContextMenu = $objContextMenu
#endregaion End GUI logic


# Show the Form - Keep it open
[void]$objForm.ShowDialog()
$objForm.Dispose()
```

As for this... [I was hopeful that would work, but using Get-Sysx on its own does nothing.], if you are saying you are not in a PowerShell session when you call this, then that is because you did not start one before the call, so, nothing to write to. So, call a message box instead and the separate call to powershell.exe, and that pause is not needed since the messagebox will stay shown until dismissed.

```
$ToggleMenuItemFunction       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Index = 2
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.Text  = "Mem and Uptime"
$ToggleMenuItemFunction.add_Click({
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($(Get-Sysx), 'Information', 0)
})
```