# PHP to Powershell CSV Parameters

Tags: php, arrays, powershell, csv, parameters

I am trying to write a php script that uses checkboxes for a user to select.  Once the user has selected their checkboxes my php script changes them (or is supposed to) to a CSV file.
This file is then loaded from a powershell script on my local machine and is then meant to carry out the commands.

The problem I am having comes in two parts and I cant seem to find the exact answer.
The first problem is the csv file that is created is in a single line. The function below sets up the csv file from the input of checkboxes however it outputs a single line csv file which I am not sure how to use.

```
function array_2_csv($array) {
$csv = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
if (is_array($item)) {
    $csv[] = array_2_csv($item);
} else {
    $csv[] = $item;
}
}
return implode(',', $csv);
}

$fh = fopen("plugin.csv","w");
                fwrite($fh,$csv_data);
                fclose($fh);
```

The second problem I believe comes from my powershell script.  Ive forced a header onto my csv file, however my switch does not seem to work. Id like to have a switch look into the array, and then execute (in this case download) some code based on what the user selected in my php file.

```
$selectedPlugin = Import-Csv "plugin.csv" -Header @("Plugin") 
switch($selectedPlugin.Plugin)
{ namefromCheckbox1 //code
 namefromCheckbox2 //code
}
```

Simply put id like the switch to download all the files that the user selected through the checkboxes earlier.

Similar to [How to pass php array to local powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349199/how-to-pass-php-array-to-local-powershell-script)

EDIT: To answer my own question, like mentioned below my csv was returning in a single line.  This was fixed by

```
$newCSV = explode(",",$csv_data);
```

and then later

```
foreach($newCSV as $item) {
fwrite($fh,$item.PHP_EOL);
```

}

Comment: Would you be able to post the content of a sample array? You can use var_dump($array) and post it. The thing is that, if your data is stored in a multidimensional array, it won't be easy to transform it into a CSV file, which is a flat format. You would probably be better off using XML, which is also natively supported by PowerShell.

Comment: When I use var_dump it returns: "array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Plugin1" [1]=> string(7) "Plugin2" }"
the csv file then looks like: Plugin1,Plugin2 (instead of Plugin1 <newline> Plugin2)
Sample size here of course was having two checkboxes 'checked'.

Comment: The CSV is definitely correct, as you used `implode()`, which joins all the entries in an array into a string, using the separator you specified. In your case, the array is `('Plugin1', 'Plugin2')` (it's not an associative array) and it becomes, as expected, `Plugin1,Plugin2`.