# PowerShell equivalent to Linux for user input

Tags: powershell

In a Linux shell script called hello.sh for example, you can take input in the following manner:

```
$name = $1
$Age = $2

echo "Hi $name!"
echo "You are $age years old!"
```

And one would execute this script on the Linux command line as the following:

```
./hello.sh Bob 99
```

Is there an equivalent way to take input in the script in PowerShell in this manner?

I have only seen [Read-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx), but this prompts the user for input after the Powershell script has executed. I would like to call the script with the required input parameters on the command line.

Comment: like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293907/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-powershell-ps1-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here is a parameterized script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
      [string] $Name
    , [int] $Age
)

Write-Host -Object "Hi $Name!","You are $Age years old!";
```

Then, to call the script:

```
.\test.ps1 -Name Trevor -Age 28;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to take input and not have to indicate the variable types like in linux?

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to declare named parameters, if you don't want to. You can use `$args[0]` and `$args[1]` instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option that is perhaps more similar in nature to the Linux example is:

```
$name = $args[0]
$Age  = $args[1]
echo "Hi $name!"
echo "You are $age years old!"
```

I am just trying to show the gap isn't so great here. Note: `echo` is an alias for [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx). Folks tend to prefer to use that over [Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx) whose output can't be captured or redirected.

Comment: Does this method store input variables in an array? That's what I'm inferring from $args[0], $args[1].

Comment: @blah Yes.  Any input arguments not bound to a defined parameter are stashed into the $args array.