# Can you pipe a string or variable into a downloaded .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell

I have file with the following contents hosted on dropbox:
(I know it is not currently calling anything)

```
function test_echo {

[CmdletBinding()]
param ( 
[Parameter (Position=0,Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
[string]$e
) 

echo $e
}
```

Is there a way to pipe information into this file before it is downloaded and executed?

ex:

`"test" | iwr DropBoxLink | iex`

and to make this echo out `test`

this honestly probably has no practical application, but I found myself wondering if it is possible so thought I'd ask.

I know I could define the string as a variable first and execute it but I just want to know if you can pipe it for principles sake

`$testEcho = "string"; iwr DropBoxLink | iex`

`> string`

Comment: You could download the file, append `"test"` to it and then execute?

Comment: 100%. there are definitely a few work arounds, but literally just for the sake of knowing is why I asked this question. I am just really curious

Comment: You can add a string argument to a powershell script :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293907/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-powershell-ps1-file

Comment: This question should be closed in its current status, because it needs more focus and needs a lot of clarification: 1. "Is there a way to pipe information into this file before it is downloaded and executed?" Seriously? You want to insert text into a file that has not been downloaded yet? I highly doubt. Please clarify. 2. With `iwr` you will get a web response status object and the actual file content will be burried in a sub property. Do you want to execute that code? Or do you want to download it into a file and let `iex` execute that file?

Comment: 3. How do you want us to make this whole thing echo "test", if your script is just a function definition and does not echo anything?
4. While your question seems to focus on "piping" a variable to the script invocation, your bounty description does not do that at all? So, what *do* you want?

Comment: Agree, should be closed as: **`Needs details or clarity`**
*This question should include more details and clarify the problem.* (unfortunately as it has a bounty, it can't be closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
"test" | % -begin { iex (irm $DropBoxUrl) } -process { $_ | test_echo }
```

- The above uses a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call's `-Begin` block to download and evaluate the script (the usual caveats re `iex` ([`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression)) apply - you should trust the source), which defines the `test_echo` function contained in the downloaded script.
- The `-Begin` script block executes *before* pipeline input is processed, which means that by the time the `-Process` script block processes (each) pipeline input object, the `test_echo` function is already defined.
- Also note that `irm` ([`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)) rather than `iwr` ([`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)) is used, given that you're only interested in the *content* of the script.

Of course, this doesn't gain you much, as you could simply use *two* statements, which has the added advantage that *all* pipeline input (should there be multiple input objects) are handled by a *single* `test_echo` invocation:

```bash
iex (irm $DropBoxUrl) # Download and effectively dot-source the script.
"test" | test_echo    # Pipe to the script's `test_echo` function.
```

A **general caveat** is that if the downloaded script contains an `exit` statement that is hit during evaluation, the *calling shell* exits *as a whole*.

- Since in effect you need to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the downloaded script in order to make its functions available, the only way to solve the `exit` problem is to *download to a (temporary) file* first, and dout-source *that*.
- If dot-sourcing isn't needed, calling via the PowerShell CLI (child process) may be an option - see below.
- [GitHub issue #5909](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5909#issuecomment-461192202) proposes a future enhancement that would allow piping `Invoke-WebRequest` (`iwr`) calls to `Invoke-Command` (`icm`) for direct-from-the-web downloading and execution, without the `exit` problem (`iwr $DropboxLink | icm`).

---

Note that **if your downloaded script were to accept pipeline input *directly***, you could use [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) as follows (`Invoke-Expression` is not an option, because it doesn't accept pipeline input):

```bash
# Assumes that the script located at $DropBoxUrl
# *itself* accepts pipeline input.
# Use . (...) if you want to *dot-source* the script, as 
# Invoke-Expression would implicitly do.
"test" | & ([scriptblock]::Create((irm $DropBoxUrl))
```

To work around the `exit` problem, you can call via the CLI and a script block, using [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) 7+ CLI, in this example; use [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell:

```bash
# Assumes that the script located at $DropBoxUrl
# *itself* accepts pipeline input.
'test' | 
  pwsh -NoProfile { 
    $input | & ([scriptblock]::Create($args[0])) 
  } -args (irm $DropBoxUrl)
```